# Active Admin Querying on Association Tables Column presence and on its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to active admin filters on an admin panel page based on its column presence.

The model association is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects, through: :orders
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :object
end

class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :orders
  has_many :orders
end
```

An order has a `quantity` column in it.
I want to filter on index page of users in my admin pages which is integrated with `active admin gem`.
Ex: I want to filter as follows:

> users with object quantity greater than 5.

I should check for association record presence and check for the quantities greater than 5 and only show that users.

> I also need the negation filters as well.

I want to check for the users who don't buy an order.

I tried to use ransack:
For this, I need to add ransack search query for each `object` records. Is there any intuitive or any way I can achieve this functionality.